# Samsung Galaxy AO1 (SM-S111DL) stuck in download mode, boot verify image load failed

Tags: samsung, boot, download-mode

How do I get past download mode (boot verify image load failed) on Samsung A01 (SM-S111D)?

Comment: Have you tried to root the phone or something like that? If boot image verification fails this means it had been modified. This can happen if the flash memory starts to fail or the system firmware has been altered.

Comment: https://www.xda-developers.com/samloader-download-updates-samsung-galaxy

Comment: Try flashing the `boot.img along with the `vbmeta.img`